# merge and delete duplicate entries

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I have a table in PostgreSQL where in some cases I end up with duplicate entries and I want to merge them together into a single one. At first, I didn't want to use a temporary table and my first approach was this.

```
WITH duplicate_entries AS (
  SELECT group_id, month, count(*)
  FROM table_a
  GROUP BY 1,2
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
), new_entries as(
  SELECT f.group_id , f.month , max(a) , max(b), sum(c) ....
  FROM table_a f
  JOIN duplicate_entries d ON f.group_id = d.group_id AND f.month = d.month
  GROUP BY 1,2
), delete_duplicate_entries as (
  DELETE
  FROM table_a f
  USING duplicate_entries e
  WHERE f.group_id = e.group_id and f.month = e.month
)INSERT INTO table_a(group_id, month, a, b, c, d)
SELECT grou_id , month, a, b, c, d
FROM new_entries;
```

but when I showed to my colleagues they weren't very comfortable with this so I ended up using a temporary table. My question is, is the above code bad and should be avoided for some reason?

Comment: If the query does what you want and has an acceptable performance, there is nothing wrong with it. I don't see the need to introduce an additional layer of complexity by using temporary tables.

Comment: Use ROW_NUMBER() to get the duplicate records and then try to delete the records